# CodeIgniter 3 not returning false in case of a DB query error

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-database

I have read as many related answers on SO related to this error I'm getting. However, NO question (or answer) is about CodeIgniter's DB active query class returning FALSE when it SHOULD (since an error occurred). All it does is print the query error to the error log file in `application/logs` and exits.

The DB_DEBUG value is false.

`$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;`

Here is the query being executed:

```
$this->db
    ->where('col_1_name', 'value')
    ->where_in('col_2_name', $array)
    ->delete('table_name');
```

The error occurs because `$array` is an empty array BUT that is not the problem - the problem is that it does **not return false** and just **prints the query error to the error log file in applications/logs/**. It is supposed to return false in case of an error, isn't it? Otherwise how will anyone catch a database error?

After it writes that query's error to the log file, it just exits the process. I've verified that by adding `log_messages()` before and after the above method.

Note: I've tried with `DB_DEBUG` = TRUE as well as FALSE and the same thing happens in both cases.

Note: CodeIgniter 3's documentation says that the `delete()` method (as well as many other DB methods) return FALSE on failiure. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how your site is set up, this is not an error. The method doesn't magically return `false` when encountering a database error.

If `db_debug` is set to `true`, CI3 halts the execution upon encountering a database error, outputs the error to the screen and logs it, but you don't get a chance to evaluate the error.

However, `db_debug` is set to `false`, you can check the value for `$this->db->error()` right after running the query and it's there where you can check if the query ran OK or not.

I tried this with a `select` statement, but the behavior is exactly the same for `delete`, `update`, etc.

```
$query = $this->db->get();
log_message('debug', "Err: ".json_encode($this->db->error()));
```

This logs:

```
DEBUG - 2020-10-09 12:09:44 --> Err: {"code":0,"message":""}
```

when there is no error, and

```
 Err: {"code":1064,"message":"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 4"}
```

when there is an error.

`$this->db->error()` is actually an array, so instead of just logging it, you may check something like

```
$err = $this->db->error();
if ($err['code'] !== 0)
{
  // do something about the error or handle the excepcion
}

else
{
  // query ran OK, keep the method going
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the documentation (as well as numerous other accepted and upvated answers on SO) say that it does return false on failiure. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::delete

Comment: "Depending on how your site is set up, this is not an error." -> Does this mean that the function does not return FALSE depending on the site's configuration? If so, can you please clarify what configuration it depends on?

Comment: can you please help me with this? It seems that the question's topic is not so popular and isn't even attracing much views, let alone answers/comments. Any more clarification will be greatly appreciated. Specifically, is the CodeIgniter documentation wrong? If not, then why isn't it returning `FALSE`?